# Why is there a comma before the participial constructions?

Tags: commas

I read the following sentence in a book:

> In war, leaving a single enemy alive to tell the story allows fear to spread.

Why is there a comma after **in war**?  As I understand it, there is a participial turn, but since it comes after, we should not put a comma. Or am I wrong and this is not a participial turn?

Comment: In that sentence, "leaving" is a gerund, not a participle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepositional phrases that start a sentence are generally ended with a comma.  This helps prevent confusion in introducing the subject.

If it were

```
In war leaving a single enemy alive ...
```

Would misdirect readers to initially think that "war" is leaving.  When you say

```
In war, leaving a single enemy alive ...
```

It is clear that the prepositional phrase indicates a situation that applies to the statement, but is not participating as part of the subject.

Comment: thanks you for help

Answer (score 1):

It’s not due to the participial phrase after the comma; it’s due to the introductory (in this case, prepositional) phrase before the comma.